# Why is MiniRedir losing authentication?

Tags: ms-office, webdav

I'm trying to use [this](https://mvc4webdav.codeplex.com/) project to integrate WebDAV into my .NET MVC2 application.

I've traced the traffic from Office to my WebDAV server, and compared it to [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd962071%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on how office determines if the document should be readonly or edit.

After Office successfully authenticates with the server I see these requests as the document is opening.

```
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS / - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft+Office+Protocol+Discovery 200 0 0 23
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS /wordstorage - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 200 0 0 5
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 PROPFIND /wordstorage - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 200 0 0 29
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 PROPFIND /wordstorage - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 200 0 0 10
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 403 0 0 7
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 PROPFIND /wordstorage - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 302 0 0 9
2014-07-22 18:41:36 127.0.0.1 PROPFIND /Account/LogOn ReturnUrl=%2fwordstorage 80 - 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 200 0 0 29
2014-07-22 18:42:25 127.0.0.1 PROPFIND /wordstorage - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 200 0 0 33
2014-07-22 18:42:25 127.0.0.1 PROPFIND /wordstorage - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 200 0 0 6
2014-07-22 18:42:59 127.0.0.1 GET /wordstorage/Test-2.docx - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.2;+IPH+1.1.21.4019;+MSOffice+12) 200 0 0 37
2014-07-22 18:42:59 127.0.0.1 HEAD /wordstorage/Test-2.docx - 80 username@mydomain.com 127.0.0.1 Microsoft+Office+Existence+Discovery 200 0 0 186
```

The first two OPTIONS and PROPFIND requests return a 200 OK, but the third OPTIONS request is denied with a 403 - forbidden code.

If authentication is successful why would MiniRedir not send authentication with the OPTIONS request?

Here's my environment:
Win 7
Office 2007
IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the IIS Webdav module is disabled ?

It seems that it may cause problems if not disabled.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, the webdav module is disabled. I also removed the WebDAV handler like so: <remove name="WebDAV" />

Comment: Sounds like Win7 MiniRedir may have a problem if the server is dropping the connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926497/custom-webdav-server-does-not-work-with-windows-7-mini-redirector/24129054#24129054